# For/next loop hang

Tags: vb.net

I have batch vb.net job, has for/next to loop in objects and create letters, insert rows to the database as in the code, the job completed occasionally and hang some times, When run using Visiual Basic 2008, it ran Ok never hang, when it ran on windows server, it hang occasionally , please can you help me find what cause it to hang.

```
 For i As Integer = 1 To myOverPmtContractInfos.Count
            'For Each myOverpmtContractInfo In myOverPmtContractInfos
            'Get all the contacts for the contract.
            If Not myDBOverpmtContact.retrieveAllByBGContract((myOverPmtContractInfos(i).billingGrp), (myOverPmtContractInfos(i).contractNbr), myOverpmtContacts) Then
                modErrorLog.WriteErrorLog(functionName & ": Error retrieving all contacts from Overpmt_Contacts for: " & myOverPmtContractInfos(i).billingGrp & " " & myOverPmtContractInfos(i).contractNbr)
                createLetters = False
                GoTo EndLetter
            End If
            'See if a second letter is due.
            If isLetterNeeded((myOverPmtContractInfos(i).daysAged), iInterval2) Then
                'Check to see if a second letter has already been processed.
                If Not doesCorrespondenceExist(myOverPmtContractInfos(i), iInterval2Type) Then
                    '  For j As Integer = 1 To myOverpmtContacts.Count
                    'For Each myOverpmtContact In myOverpmtContacts
                    'Populate a corrsepondence class object for the creation of the notice.
                    myOverpmtCorrespondence.billingGrp = myOverPmtContractInfos(i).billingGrp
                    myOverpmtCorrespondence.contractNbr = myOverPmtContractInfos(i).contractNbr
                    myOverpmtCorrespondence.corrNbr = myDBOverpmtCorrespondence.getNextNbr((myOverPmtContractInfos(i).billingGrp), (myOverPmtContractInfos(i).contractNbr))
                    myOverpmtCorrespondence.corrDate = todaysdate
                    myOverpmtCorrespondence.corrTypeId = iInterval2Type
                    myOverpmtCorrespondence.comments = ""
                    myOverpmtCorrespondence.postDate = todaysdate
                    myOverpmtCorrespondence.lastUpdated = todaysdate

                    If myOverpmtContacts.Count > 0 Then
                        modLetters.createCorrsepondence(myOverPmtContractInfos(i), myOverpmtContacts(1), myOverpmtCorrespondence)
                        iLetterCount = iLetterCount + 1
                        ' insertCorrespondence(myOverpmtCorrespondence)
                        modErrorLog.WriteErrorLog(functionName & ": 2nd Letter created for: " & myOverpmtCorrespondence.billingGrp & " / " & myOverpmtCorrespondence.contractNbr & " / " & myOverpmtContacts(1).firstname)
                    End If

                    If myOverpmtContacts.Count > 1 Then
                        modLetters.createCorrsepondence(myOverPmtContractInfos(i), myOverpmtContacts(2), myOverpmtCorrespondence)
                        iLetterCount = iLetterCount + 1
                        modErrorLog.WriteErrorLog(functionName & ": 2nd Letter created for: " & myOverpmtCorrespondence.billingGrp & " / " & myOverpmtCorrespondence.contractNbr & " / " & myOverpmtContacts(2).firstname)
                    End If

                    If myOverpmtContacts.Count > 2 Then
                        modLetters.createCorrsepondence(myOverPmtContractInfos(i), myOverpmtContacts(3), myOverpmtCorrespondence)
                        iLetterCount = iLetterCount + 1
                        modErrorLog.WriteErrorLog(functionName & ": 2nd Letter created for: " & myOverpmtCorrespondence.billingGrp & " / " & myOverpmtCorrespondence.contractNbr & " / " & myOverpmtContacts(3).firstname)
                    End If
                    GoTo EndLetter
                End If
            End If
            'See if a third letter is due.
            If isLetterNeeded((myOverPmtContractInfos(i).daysAged), iInterval3) Then
                'Check to see if a third letter has already been processed.
                If Not doesCorrespondenceExist(myOverPmtContractInfos(i), iInterval3Type) Then
                    'For Each myOverpmtContact In myOverpmtContacts
                    '   For k As Integer = 1 To myOverpmtContacts.Count
                    'Populate a corrsepondence class object for the creation of the notice.
                    myOverpmtCorrespondence.billingGrp = myOverPmtContractInfos(i).billingGrp
                    myOverpmtCorrespondence.contractNbr = myOverPmtContractInfos(i).contractNbr
                    myOverpmtCorrespondence.corrNbr = myDBOverpmtCorrespondence.getNextNbr((myOverPmtContractInfos(i).billingGrp), (myOverPmtContractInfos(i).contractNbr))
                    myOverpmtCorrespondence.corrDate = todaysdate
                    myOverpmtCorrespondence.corrTypeId = iInterval3Type
                    myOverpmtCorrespondence.comments = ""
                    myOverpmtCorrespondence.postDate = todaysdate
                    myOverpmtCorrespondence.lastUpdated = todaysdate

                    If myOverpmtContacts.Count > 0 Then
                        modLetters.createCorrsepondence(myOverPmtContractInfos(i), myOverpmtContacts(1), myOverpmtCorrespondence)
                        'modErrorLog.WriteErrorLog(functionName & ": Error creating 2nd Letter for: " & myOverpmtCorrespondence.billingGrp & " / " & myOverpmtCorrespondence.contractNbr)
                        iLetterCount = iLetterCount + 1
                        insertCorrespondence(myOverpmtCorrespondence)
                        modErrorLog.WriteErrorLog(functionName & ": Final Letter created for: " & myOverpmtCorrespondence.billingGrp & " / " & myOverpmtCorrespondence.contractNbr & " / " & myOverpmtContacts(1).firstname)
                    End If
                    If myOverpmtContacts.Count > 1 Then
                        modLetters.createCorrsepondence(myOverPmtContractInfos(i), myOverpmtContacts(2), myOverpmtCorrespondence)
                        'modErrorLog.WriteErrorLog(functionName & ": Error creating 2nd Letter for: " & myOverpmtCorrespondence.billingGrp & " / " & myOverpmtCorrespondence.contractNbr)
                        iLetterCount = iLetterCount + 1
                        modErrorLog.WriteErrorLog(functionName & ": Final Letter created for: " & myOverpmtCorrespondence.billingGrp & " / " & myOverpmtCorrespondence.contractNbr & " / " & myOverpmtContacts(2).firstname)
                    End If
                    If myOverpmtContacts.Count > 2 Then
                        modLetters.createCorrsepondence(myOverPmtContractInfos(i), myOverpmtContacts(3), myOverpmtCorrespondence)
                        'modErrorLog.WriteErrorLog(functionName & ": Error creating 2nd Letter for: " & myOverpmtCorrespondence.billingGrp & " / " & myOverpmtCorrespondence.contractNbr)
                        iLetterCount = iLetterCount + 1
                        modErrorLog.WriteErrorLog(functionName & ": Final Letter created for: " & myOverpmtCorrespondence.billingGrp & " / " & myOverpmtCorrespondence.contractNbr & " / " & myOverpmtContacts(3).firstname)
                    End If

                End If
            End If
EndLetter:
            'Reset the contacts collect for the next contract.
            'UPGRADE_NOTE: Object myOverpmtContacts may not be destroyed until it is garbage collected. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="6E35BFF6-CD74-4B09-9689-3E1A43DF8969"'
            myOverpmtContacts = Nothing
            myOverpmtContacts = New OverpmtContacts
        Next i

        createLetters = True

EndFunction:
        modErrorLog.WriteErrorLog("Number of letters created: " & iLetterCount)
        'UPGRADE_NOTE: Object myOverPmtContractInfos may not be destroyed until it is garbage collected. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="6E35BFF6-CD74-4B09-9689-3E1A43DF8969"'
        myOverPmtContractInfos = Nothing
        'UPGRADE_NOTE: Object myDBOverpmtContractInfo may not be destroyed until it is garbage collected. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="6E35BFF6-CD74-4B09-9689-3E1A43DF8969"'
        myDBOverpmtContractInfo = Nothing
        'UPGRADE_NOTE: Object myCodeTranslate may not be destroyed until it is garbage collected. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="6E35BFF6-CD74-4B09-9689-3E1A43DF8969"'
        myCodeTranslate = Nothing
        'UPGRADE_NOTE: Object myOverpmtContacts may not be destroyed until it is garbage collected. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="6E35BFF6-CD74-4B09-9689-3E1A43DF8969"'
        myOverpmtContacts = Nothing
        'UPGRADE_NOTE: Object myDBOverpmtContact may not be destroyed until it is garbage collected. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="6E35BFF6-CD74-4B09-9689-3E1A43DF8969"'
        myDBOverpmtContact = Nothing
        myOverpmtCorrespondence = New OverpmtCorrespondence
        myDBOverpmtCorrespondence = New DBOverpmtCorrespondence
    End Function
```

Comment: I shall spend as much time studying your code as you spent formatting it.

Comment: I see GoTo's.  I see problems.

Comment: Another thing that springs to mind is that you probably need `For i As Integer = 0 To myOverPmtContractInfos.Count - 1` as you appear to be using `i` as an index into some kind of collection called `myOverPmtContractInfos`. Index numbers start at zero.

Comment: It's probably due to the `GoTo`s as Lars said. Anyhow, you could place breakpoints on certain lines and see which ones are not hit.

Comment: Thank you for replying, It is not going to deadlock, it is just hanging so I think GOTO is not the issue, also when I debug it, it completed OK does not hang so putting Breakpoints will not help,

Comment: I noticed you are outputting logs, what is the most recent log entry after it hangs?  That could give you an indication of where it is hanging.

Comment: Chris, it is not consistent, it hang every time on different line of debug, I will get crazy to know why it is hang ?

Answer (score 0):

When an application behaves sometimes, but not all the time, it's usually (but not always) caused by external factors.

If it's caused by external factors:

1. Consider what other processes are running on the machine. Are they tying up the CPU?
2. Consider whether or not another application has the database tied down. This is unlikely, if you are using a serious DBMS such as Oracle or SQL Server, but is worth looking into.
3. Consider whether or not your network is the issue. Are you trying to access resources (files or folders) that are used by other processes, or which are located in geographically remote locations, and accessible only over relatively slow connections?

If you can eliminate external factors, review your code.

1. Are you leaking memory? If you are not properly releasing objects in a timely fashion, you may be causing the garbage collector to kick off due to memory pressure.
2. Are you not closing database connections quickly enough and releasing them back into the connection pool? (Note: Be sure to release data readers as quickly as you can. These are notorious for keeping your connection open.)
3. Are you talking to services or components over DCOM? Are they reliable?
4. Are you invoking web services? If so, all bets are off as to their responsiveness. You should provide a means of allowing for a reasonable timeframe in which they can respond, and gracefully fail.
5. Are you writing to a centralized log file, database or queue? If so, how are you managing concurrency when doing so?

These are just a few of the things I can think off the top of my head that should be considered when sporadic behaviors crop up.